# GLSL dynamic array index

Tags: arrays, indexing, glsl

I have 10 constant variables (that have random numbers).
I want to access them with a dynamic index.

```
float getNumber(int index) {
  return array[index];
}
```

This gives the error "index expression must be constant"
I cannot make the index constant.

So i came up with this solution:

```
float getNumber(int index) {
  if (index == 0) return array[0];
  if (index == 1) return array[1];
  if (index == 2) return array[2];
  if (index == 3) return array[3];
  .....
}
```

This seems like a weird thing to do, is this normal?
Is there a better way?

Comment: Which OpenGL version (context) do you use? Most likely the index is allowed to be the control variable of a `for`-loop, too.

Comment: i want to make it for mobile(glsl es), but i was using http://glslsandbox.com/ for experimenting

Comment: In [GLSL ES 1.00](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf), the index has to be a constant, a loop index or a combination of both.

Comment: ok, thanks, a loop would look a bit better